# Does recursive loop not proceed to the next item if it fails?

Tags: python, loops, recursion

So I have this homework almost done, but only after I figure out why the heck
this loop does not continue when I call it recursively.

I will take a name as an input and return his children and father as an output.

e.g., Kanky's children are satan,malan,ulan,yugi
and satan's children are ben & Alan
malan has no child, my tree looks something like this:

```
T=["Kanky",["satan",["ben","ian"],"Alan"],"malan",["yugi","yuppi"]]
```

My code:

```
def find_the_man(T,name):

    F = tree[0]     # the head of list
    C = tree[1:]    # tail of the list
    kids = ""       # find the kids and append to this str
    if F==name:
        i = 0
        while i<len(C):
          #do some things to find the children
          #return them


    for i in C:      ### this loop tries to find the man with no child
        if i==name:
            return [daddy,notfound] ### if it finds, returns it

    for i in C:             ### this is my whole thing, it takes just the
        if type(i)==list:   ### first list(unfortenately), if it finds the 
            find_the_man(i,name)  ### man by doing the actions on top,
        else:continue             ### it returns the child, but it is not able to
                              ### proceed the next lists, so when i give an input
return [notfound,notfound]    ### like (T,"yugi"), it gives notfound :(
```

Comment: So you're calling your `find_the_man()` function in that loop, but not doing anything with the result. Why call it in that case? Maybe you should build up a list of the results, and return that, or something...?

Comment: It is doing something actually, but just for the first nested loop, if it fails to find it in that list, it couldnt proceed to next list as I wanted..
what kind of result list should I build, because in that case it would be harder for me to find the children of that man?

Comment: You probably want to do `return find_the_man(i,name)`.  That's a common recursive strategy (the only one I regularly see/use).  Otherwise recursing doesn't do anything... it's just ignored (as already mentioned).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand when I return it, it doesnt change anything, I tried a hundred ways of calling the function with the next nested list, "return"s, "helper function"s but they just returned me [notfound]. I ended up with this solution but this doesnt work either, I could have flatten the whole tree so that I could find the man that I look for, but I am told that I cannot play with the tree structure :(

Comment: This is usually the point where I find a [good debugger](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggers), and step through it line by line.  It may be boring, but you'll solve the problem faster that way (and maybe even learn something in the process).

Comment: that would be a good solution if my finals were not so near, but if I can find the time, I will use this site to check my code 
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be honest, I didn't want to analyze your code to look for where is the problem, but i know how to do properly.

Check this out:

```
def find_the_man( T, name,  p = None):
    r = False 
    for i in T: 
        if type( i ) == list: 
            r = find_the_man( i, name, T[0] )
            if r:
               break
        elif i == name:
            return ( p, [ i[0] if type(i) == list else i for i in T[ 1: ] ] ) if T.index(i) == 0 else ( T[0], None )
    return r 

T= [ "Kanky", [ "satan", [ "ben", "ian" ], "Alan" ], "malan", [ "yugi", "yuppi" ] ] 
# function return tuple ( parent, list_of_children )
find_the_man( T, "Kanky" )  # (None, ['satan', 'malan', 'yugi'])
find_the_man( T, "satan" )  # ('Kanky', ['ben', 'Alan'])
find_the_man( T, "ben" )    # ('satan', ['ian'])
find_the_man( T, "malan" )  # ('Kanky', None)
find_the_man( T, "yugi" )   # ('Kanky', ['yuppi'])
find_the_man( T, "yuppi" )  # ('yugi', None)
find_the_man(T, "stranger" )# False
```